# GraphicalDatePickerStyle() is December text and time squashed bug

Tags: swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedDate: Date = Date()
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("›", selection: self.$selectedDate)
            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle() )
            
            
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

once you Tapp on the date picker the graph becomes fixed

anyone know of away around this thanks!

[image: broken]

[image: once tapped its fixed]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug. But You can fix it by adding horizontal padding or adding custom padding (padding should be > 15)

```
struct ContentViewDate: View {
    @State private var selectedDate: Date = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate)
            .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
            .padding(.horizontal) // <<-- Add horizontal padding or set .padding(15)
    }
}
```